# Invoke an Alexa skill, create a cron-like task, and then receive periodical updates

Tags: alexa-skills-kit

Trying to implement a hosted Alexa skill that looks like follows:

- **t<sub>0</sub> (me):** Alexa, ask whatever to check car location during 30 minutes
- **t<sub>0</sub> (alexa):** Ok, I'll give you updates every minute during 30 minutes
- **t<sub>0</sub> (alexa):** Car is 3.8 Km away
- **t<sub>60</sub> (alexa):** Car is 3.2 Km away
- **t<sub>120</sub> (alexa):** Car is 2.8 Km away
- **t<sub>180</sub> (alexa):** Car is 1.1 Km away
- **t<sub>200</sub> (me):** Alexa, ask whatever to stop updates
- **t<sub>200</sub> (alexa):** Updates stopped

So, basically the request handler executed at t<sub>0</sub> needs to create some kind of timer that every 60 seconds is able to contact the echo device, interrupt whatever in going on, and give the update. It  looks like the Proactive Events API is what I'm looking for, but not sure at all if that's the way to go or if what I want to do if even possible.

Answer (score 0):

Currently the way to do work and then return information to the user is using the Proactive Events API. This however ends up in the customer getting a notification to open and review and then potentially having to return to your skill for additional information. Notifications have a number of rules and are currently very templated controlling the experience.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/smapi/proactive-events-api.html

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/docs/alexa/alexa-voice-service/notifications-overview.html

Announced on August 22nd of 2020 what a new feature that allows skill resumption. This will be the way to go in the very near future. The use case seems to be exactly what you are looking for.

https://developer.amazon.com/en-US/blogs/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/2020/07/make-it-easier-for-customers-to-pick-up-where-they-left-off-with-skill-resumption

> Customer: “Alexa, get me a ride home.”

> Alexa: “Ok, an UberX from your current location at Sixth Avenue and Blanchard Street, to  home, right?”

> Customer: “Yes”

> Alexa: “Looking for a driver. I’ll let you know when I have a match.”

So I would say that you are on the right track, but the better way is coming.